# intellisense not see global temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense

I open a new query in ssms and create a global temp table.  I then open a new query window in ssms and write sql to insert data in the fields.  But in the new query window intellisense does not recognize the temporary table. The sql works fine and the data is inserted into the temp table and I can work with the temp table but without intellisense.  I can return to the original query window where the table was created and intellisense work fine.  I have tried refreshing intellisense, it doesn't work.  Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Table code is

```
CREATE TABLE ##UserInfo
(

    [UserId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [strEmail] varchar(50)  NULL,
    [strLastName] varchar(50)  NULL,
    [strFirstName] varchar(50)  NULL,

)
```

Insert code

```
insert into ##Userinfo(strLastName,strFirstName)

select distinct POC_DATA.POC_LNAME, POC_DATA.POC_FNAME
from POC_DATA
```

The bold is the part intellisense does not recognize in the different query window

Comment: Native Intellisense does not work very well with temp tables, and definitely not going to work with a global temp table. Keep in mind that global temp tables are evil and they cause all sorts of issues with concurrency.

Comment: Have you seen any documentation that indicates that intellisense SHOULD recognize the global temp table that is coded in another query window?   This sounds like expected behavior to me.

Answer (score 5):

So far the only "trick" I have been able to come up with is to include the "CREATE TABLE" command in a block that will never execute, but intellisense will see, like so:

```
IF 1=0
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE ##UserInfo (
      [UserId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
      [strEmail] varchar(50)  NULL,
      [strLastName] varchar(50)  NULL,
      [strFirstName] varchar(50)  NULL,
   );
END
```

It would be nice if you could put into a comment, but alas intellisense ignores that.